# Custom Windows Installer to install multiple software from remote location

Tags: windows, wix, installation, nsis, advanced-installer

I need someone to point me to the right direction. I am new to Windows Installer and I have researched WiX, Advanced Installer, Inno Setup and NSIS and I don't even know the correct keyword to look for to see if they solve my problem.

What I want to accomplish is:
I have many PC software for user to download. Each of them is a separate install file (exe or msi).
What I hope to accomplish is to create a **Custom Windows Installer** that is able to accomplish these during installation process:

1. List all PC software available for user to download/install.
2. Allow user to choose which PC software they would like to download/install.
3. Download/Install these PC software for user.

Each PC software is hosted in different location from where user executes Custom Windows Installer.

Is there any solution that meets my requirement?

thank you all, appreciate your help.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I would prefer [NSIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nullsoft_Scriptable_Install_System) or [Inno Setup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inno_Setup). They are free (open source) and easy to learn.

They are script-based, so basically you can do everything. There are a lot of plugins available for them (for example, for downloading files), and you can adjust any aspect of the installer.

1. Create a custom page where you list the software
2. Selected software will be downloaded
3. Software will be executed

NSIS has its own language similar to C, and Inno Setup uses Pascal language for scripting.

Comment: I have tried both Advanced Installer and Inno Setup. Although Advanced Installer is easier to use at first, but Inno Setup is free and can basically do whatever I want to do.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this for sure with Advanced Installer and [WiX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WiX).

In Advanced Installer you have a built-in support for [suite installations](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-creating-suite-installations.html), as in the linked tutorial. In this example the applications are included in the setup package, but you can configure them to be downloaded from a URL too, during the installation. Our support team (disclaimer: I work on Advanced Installer) is very responsive so if you have any questions check out the forums or send an email to support.

In WiX there is a bundle support called [Burn](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/). Of course the learning curve for WiX is a little bit steeper, but that's how it is with OSS :)